# Saving a raster with writeRaster and getting an error

Tags: raster, r, lidr

I am trying to save a Rumble Index derived from a LAS point cloud catalog. The code follows [an example from](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/outbox.html#outbox-rumple-index) and it does provide a graphic output with the `plot()` command. However, I wish to save it to my hard drive with the `writeRaster` command and I get an error. The code I am running is below.

```
source("D:/TAGB/Scripts/0000_setup.R")

rumple_index_surface = function(cluster, res)
{
  las = readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  las <- filter_surfacepoints(las, 1)
  rumple <- grid_metrics(las, ~rumple_index(X,Y,Z), res)
  bbox <- raster::extent(cluster)
  rumple <- raster::crop(rumple, bbox)
  return(rumple)
}

project <- readLAScatalog("D:/TAGB/2018/LAZ_N2/")

opt_chunk_buffer(project) <- 1
opt_select(project) <- "xyz"
opt <- list(raster_alignment = 25, automerge = TRUE)
output <- catalog_apply(project, rumple_index_surface, res = 25, .options = opt)

plot(output, col = height.colors(50))

rumple <- raster(output)

writeRaster(rumple, name = "D:/TAGB/2018/Metrics/rumpleIndex_25m.img", overwrite=TRUE)
#> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
#>  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "missing"
```

Comment: In `writeRaster()` (from `raster` package) the second argument is `filename` not `name`.

Comment: Thank you JRR. I'm embarrassed for not noticing that error. However, thrilled that I can continue on my project. Thanks again.